# Generate all sets of size N from a SMALLER set of size K objects

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of K objects, generate all sets of size N (where N > K). For example, starting with the set {1,2} (K=2}, generating all sets of size N=3 would result in the following output sets: {1,1,1} {1,1,2},{1,2,1},{2,1,1},{2,2,1},{2,1,2},{1,2,2},{2,2,2}. What is an efficient algorithm to generate such sets?

Note for Ken White: My research has only turned up algorithms dealing with C(m n) where n < m; algorithms for permutations and combinations of items from a given set. That is not what I am trying to do. I am not posting code, because without an algorithm, what will I try to have my code accomplish?

Maybe my earlier posting was not clear, but your response - "Please excuse my total lack of effort, but can someone write this code for me? Be back later to pick it up. Tx bye. – Ken White Jun 27 at 22:54" was really professional and helpful.

Comment: This is an impossible goal, because `{2,2,2}` is not a possible set. If you are working with lists instead the problem is quite tractable but then it's not clear what work even remains to be done. It's very easy to sample N times from a set of M items, with replacement.

Comment: You're counting in base `K` the numbers `0` to `(K^N) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an order to the sets, so you don't re-visit any you've already dealt with. Start with all the sets where `K[0]` occurs `0` times, and `K[1]` occurs `0` times, and finally `K[last]` appears `N` times. Then consider when `K[last-1]` appears `1` times, etc, short-circuiting your search each time the sum of elements you've already assigned reaches `N`.

Pseudo-code:

```
addAllSets(N, K, 0, new int[K], new Set()) //Initial call

addAllSets(int targetCount, int K, int index, int[] prefix, Set allSets){
    if (index < k): //We still have the rest of the elements to consider
        for i in range 0 to targetCount - 1: 
            prefix[index] = i //Try it with i of this element
            addAllSets(targetCount - i, K, index + 1, prefix.copy, allSets) //Recursively check remaining elements
    prefix[index] = targetCount //Or just fill in the rest of the set with copies of this element
    allSets.add(prefix) //Add this to the set of sets
```

prefix stores counts for some number of elements (total count will always be `K - targetCount` when the function is invoked.) Every time we "fill it up", we add it to the set of all sets.